# Is there a way to transition a BottomSheet to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

Currently, I have a bottomSheetBehavior layout that is reused in several activities, but requirements have changed and logic inside it has increased. My question is, is there a way to keep the functionality of bottom sheet collapsed, but when expanded, transition to an activity?

Specifically, when the bottom sheet is collapsed, allow clicks and scroll on the rest of the view, but when expanded, start a new activity so logic can be handled there.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to set the Bottom Sheet Behaviour inside a View Model, and then, the view model posts whatever data to the view using Live Data, at least that ensures logic is contained in one place.